# Using Python for QC'ing Excel file with multiple tabs

Tags: python, hp-quality-center

I am a little new to Python and have a couple questions for the experts here. I am looking to see if it is possible to have a python code go through an Excel File and run a series of checks in multiple tabs in the file. After it runs those checks, I need each tab in the file to be converted into a CSV then.

I use a SAS code for QC'ing these Excel Files, but it is clunky and always doesnt work right. I was wondering what you guys think about this being possible in Python.

Comment: you could use pandas DataFrame. 
read_excel.
to_csv.

Comment: It’s possible; however; these types of questions (where the answers are simply “yes” or “no”) are not good fits for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you questions is quite complex and could be easily replied with a yes :-)
First step is to learn the openpyxl (I would suggest that), but there are multiple excel module for python.
Another way might be with pandas module to convert the file into csv --> Anyway if I remember correctly CSV will not support multi tab. So you should read tab by tab and save in a single CSV file each time.

Regarding writing back into QC, then please have a look at link

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/15.5-15.5.1/online_help/Content/APIs/API_ALM_REST_Site_Admin.htm

I am using the REST API (with python scripts) to upload all the results into QC and of course also excel/log files.

There should be also an excel plugin to connect excel with QC. Maybe if you have structure excel, you could even try out that.

Hope that help. Wish you a nice day.